# Where is the onclick function in this HTML snippet defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I read this code on [HTMLCodeTutorial.com](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_onClick.html):

```
<FORM>
<TABLE BORDER CELLPADDING=3>
<TR>
<TD><NOBR>radius: <INPUT NAME="Circle_radius" SIZE=4></NOBR></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="Circle_calc(this.form);" VALUE="calculate"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR="#AACCFF">
<NOBR>circumference: <INPUT NAME="Circle_circumference" SIZE=9></NOBR><BR>
<NOBR>area: <INPUT NAME="Circle_area" SIZE=9></NOBR></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
```

I can’t understand `OnClick="Circle_calc(this.form);"`

`Circle_calc(this.form)` isn't defined anywhere. How does this function work? Is it a built-in function in HTML?

Comment: You should find a tutorial where the HTML tags are in lowercase.

Comment: You should find a tutorial where the HTML tags are not non-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built-in. If you look at the source code, it's defined as:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function Circle_calc(GeoForm)
{
var CircleRadius = GeoForm.Circle_radius.value;
if (CircleRadius >= 0)
   {
   GeoForm.Circle_circumference.value =  2 * Math.PI * CircleRadius ;
   GeoForm.Circle_area.value =  Math.PI * Math.pow(CircleRadius, 2) ;
   }
else
   {
   GeoForm.Circle_circumference.value =  "";
   GeoForm.Circle_area.value =  "";
   }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Darn it Kei, you beat me to it :-)  mehdi, this is the script it runs, do a right click on the page and choose view source.  I've pasted the HTML source in my answer, but kei got there first :-)

Comment: if we define a function in php can i replace with Circle_calc();?

Comment: @mehdi Here's an example of that: [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5310).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's a pretty crappy tutorial using outmoded techniques and non-standard HTML elements.

`Circle_calc` is not a builtin function... the tutorial has simply neglected to define it, or indicate that it is defined elsewhere.

Strongly suggest you find another site for your tutorials, but unfortunately have none to recommend as I haven't needed one in a while :S

Comment: Second to another tutorial - apart from breaking standards it appears to be very old.

Comment: if it possible we define a function in html?

Answer (score 1):

They have been quite naughty methinks,

If you do a view page source on that page, and look at the way THEY'VE done the form, then you'll see this:

```
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function Circle_calc(GeoForm)
{
var CircleRadius = GeoForm.Circle_radius.value;
if (CircleRadius >= 0)
   {
   GeoForm.Circle_circumference.value =  2 * Math.PI * CircleRadius ;
   GeoForm.Circle_area.value =  Math.PI * Math.pow(CircleRadius, 2) ;
   }
else
   {
   GeoForm.Circle_circumference.value =  "";
   GeoForm.Circle_area.value =  "";
   }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>


<P>

<FORM>
<TABLE BORDER CELLPADDING=3>
<TR>
<TD><NOBR>radius: <INPUT NAME="Circle_radius" SIZE=4></NOBR></TD>

<TD><INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="Circle_calc(this.form);" VALUE="calculate"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR="#AACCFF">
<NOBR>circumference: <INPUT NAME="Circle_circumference" SIZE=9></NOBR><BR>
<NOBR>area: <INPUT NAME="Circle_area" SIZE=9></NOBR></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>

<P>
```

As you can see, you now have the HTML code in context, and you can actually see the script that the HTML executes.  And as the script is inside the HTML file, you wouldn't need to have an import (if that's the right phrase) at the top of your HTML file telling it which script file to use.

Also I would strongly recommend using the W3c Schools tutorials, they're miles better and they can be found here:  http://www.w3schools.com/w3c/w3c_html.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually the function is defined, it just isn't showed in the tutorial code - look at the source to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of the tutorial it is stated:

```
`onClick` gives the script to run when the user clicks on the input. `onClick` applies
 to buttons (submit, reset, and button), checkboxes, radio buttons, and form upload buttons.
```

The function is defined in the source code of the page:

```
function Circle_calc(GeoForm)
{
    ...
}
```

The function accepts the form as an argument that will be used by the JavaScript function to perform read/write operations over the values in the text fields of the form.

I hope this helps.